# Not exists in sql query

Tags: oracle-11g

I'm using oracle database

I need to display customer id and customer name of those customers who have not purchased at all from any retail outlet using not exists

My query:

```
select customerid,customername
from customer c
where  not exists (
select p.customerid
from purchasebill p,retailoutlet r,customer c
where p.customerid=c.customerid and p.retailoutletid=r.retailoutletid group by p.customerid);
```

I supposed to get 3 records but i'm getting output as no rows selected, instead of not exists if i use not in, the output is correct.What's wrong in the above code please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, `NOT IN` is not the same as `NOT EXISTS`.

```
create table customer (customerid number);
create table purchasebill (customerid number, retailoutletid number);
create table retailoutlet (retailoutletid number);

insert into customer values (1);
insert into customer values (2);

insert into purchasebill values (1, 1);
insert into purchasebill values (null, 3);

insert into retailoutlet values (1);
insert into retailoutlet values (3);

commit;
```

Let's find customers without purchasebill (`customerid = 2`). FIrst with a naive `NOT IN`:

```
SQL> select * from customer c where c.customerid not in (select p.customerid from purchasebill p);

no rows selected
```

Now with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SQL> select * from customer c where not exists (select 1 from purchasebill p where p.customerid = c.customerid);

CUSTOMERID
----------
         2
```

`NOT IN` did not provide the result we expected. It's because the way `NOT IN` works. If any row of the subquery returns `NULL`, `NOT IN` will return `FALSE`, so no result in this case.

Now your queries:

```
SQL> select * from customer c where not exists (select p.customerid from customer c, purchasebill p, retailoutlet r where p.customerid = c.customerid and r.retailoutletid = p.retailoutletid);

no rows selected

SQL> select * from customer c where customerid not in (select p.customerid from customer c, purchasebill p, retailoutlet r where p.customerid = c.customerid and r.retailoutletid = p.retailoutletid);

CUSTOMERID
----------
         2
```

The problem with the `NOT EXISTS` query is that you have `customer c` both in the outer query and the subquery. The subquery uses `customer c` from its inside, not the `customer c` from the outer query. Because of this, the subquery always returns data, so `NOT EXISTS` will always evaluate to `FALSE`, hence no result.

The `NOT IN` version works, because the inner query is not a correlated subquery, it does not use `customer c` from the outside, but the inside. The inner query returns customers who made purchases, without `NULL`s, because the join to `purchasebill p` eliminates them. With no `NULL`s to worry anymore, `NOT IN` works as naively expected.

If you want to make `NOT EXISTS` work, remove `customer c` from the subquery, so it becomes a correlated subquery:

```
SQL> select * from customer c where not exists (select 1 from purchasebill p, retailoutlet r where p.customerid = c.customerid and r.retailoutletid = p.retailoutletid);

CUSTOMERID
----------
         2
```